# Store very large numbers in scientific notation form in SQL

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

We have an application which returns result of large calculations in exponent to base form like 1.8e+6.

We need to save this value in database. Can we store this in database as integer or it should be converted to a number first ?

please help

Comment: What is the type of this value in application?

Comment: The value displays in a textbox. Only to read value from textbox.

Comment: the type to save that in is float in my opinion, that way you can save up to 1+e300 and beyond and down to -e300 and smaller - Integer would throw away very small values such as 1e-06

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert 1.8e+6 directly into a table column of type "int", it will be interpreted (Tested with SQL Server 2014).

Beware that "int" only can handle numbers as large as 1.8e+31, for larger numbers you'll need to use bigint.

Comment: That value is just an example. The returned values are larger. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server supports floating point numbers, both 4-byte and 8-byte.  These accept constants such as `1e4` in exponential notation.  They are also fully supported by the mathematical functions.

You can read about the types in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

I think the biggest you can use is:

```
DECLARE @d float(53)
```

It ranges between -1.79E+308 and 1.79E+308

Comment: that's the one to use here, it's true the large values might fit in integer, but there could also be very small values such as 1e-10 where an integer is going to round off to zero

Answer (score 1):

SQL will consume the scientific notation directly

```
Select val1 = 1.8e+6
      ,val2 = cast(1.8e+6 as bigint)
      ,val3 = cast('1.8e+6' as float)
```

Returns

```
val1    val2    val3
1800000 1800000 1800000
```